# Error: "module 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'Nadam'" in Jupyter Notebook using R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, jupyter

The German actuarial organisation has a yearly data science challenge for which I am trying to check out the 2022 winners' Jupyter Notebook which they wrote in R.

I run Python (and hence, Jupyter) using miniconda. I installed conda navigator and installed all the required packages (first and foremost obviously r, and r-irkernel). At some point in the notebook, the authors start using keras. They design a neural network and create a model. So we end up calling this code:

```r
# other calls to libraries that are imported before this chunk:
# library(rpart)
# library(repr)
# library(rpart.plot)
# library(tidyverse)
# library(lme4)

library(keras)

# Design, VehBrand, Region and LogVol are outputs of layer_input
# Response is the output of layer_dense

model <- keras_model(inputs = c(Design, VehBrand, Region, LogVol), outputs = c(Response))
model %>% compile(optimizer = optimizer_nadam(), loss = 'poisson')

summary(model)
```

When I run the second to last line, I get the following error:

```
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent): AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'Nadam'
Traceback:

1. model %>% compile(optimizer = optimizer_nadam(), loss = "poisson")
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
8. function_list[[k]](value)
9. compile(., optimizer = optimizer_nadam(), loss = "poisson")
10. compile.keras.engine.training.Model(., optimizer = optimizer_nadam(), 
  .     loss = "poisson")
11. optimizer_nadam()
12. do.call(keras$optimizers$Nadam, args)
13. keras$optimizers$Nadam
14. `$.python.builtin.module`(keras$optimizers, "Nadam")
15. `$.python.builtin.object`(x, name)
16. py_get_attr_or_item(x, name, TRUE)
17. py_get_attr(x, name)
18. py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent)
```

It looks to me like Jupyter is trying to call a tensorflow function from Python. Is this assumption correct? How do I fix my error?

Thank you!

Edit 1:

DarknessPlusPlus suggested using

```r
model %>% compile(optimizer="Nadam", loss="poisson")
```

instead of

```r
model %>% compile(optimizer=optimizer_nadam(), loss="poisson")
```

Right after creating the model using this new line, my kernel dies when trying to create a fit using this model. Here is the output of the summary function:

```
Model: "model"
________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)              Output Shape      Param #  Connected to               
================================================================================
VehBrand (InputLayer)     [(None, 1)]       0                                   
________________________________________________________________________________
Region (InputLayer)       [(None, 1)]       0                                   
________________________________________________________________________________
BrandEmb (Embedding)      (None, 1, 2)      22       VehBrand[0][0]             
________________________________________________________________________________
RegionEmb (Embedding)     (None, 1, 2)      44       Region[0][0]               
________________________________________________________________________________
Design (InputLayer)       [(None, 7)]       0                                   
________________________________________________________________________________
Brand_flat (Flatten)      (None, 2)         0        BrandEmb[0][0]             
________________________________________________________________________________
Region_flat (Flatten)     (None, 2)         0        RegionEmb[0][0]            
________________________________________________________________________________
concate (Concatenate)     (None, 11)        0        Design[0][0]               
                                                     Brand_flat[0][0]           
                                                     Region_flat[0][0]          
________________________________________________________________________________
hidden1 (Dense)           (None, 20)        240      concate[0][0]              
________________________________________________________________________________
hidden2 (Dense)           (None, 15)        315      hidden1[0][0]              
________________________________________________________________________________
hidden3 (Dense)           (None, 10)        160      hidden2[0][0]              
________________________________________________________________________________
Network (Dense)           (None, 1)         11       hidden3[0][0]              
________________________________________________________________________________
LogVol (InputLayer)       [(None, 1)]       0                                   
________________________________________________________________________________
Add (Add)                 (None, 1)         0        Network[0][0]              
                                                     LogVol[0][0]               
________________________________________________________________________________
Response (Dense)          (None, 1)         2        Add[0][0]                  
================================================================================
Total params: 794
Trainable params: 792
Non-trainable params: 2
________________________________________________________________________________
```

This is identical to the output of the Jupyter Notebook as it was submitted by the authors. Here is the next line of code that is called:

```r
# Xlearn, Brlearn, Relearn, Vlearn, Ylearn are outputs of as.matrix().
fit <- model %>% 
        fit(
          list(Xlearn, Brlearn, Relearn, Vlearn), 
          Ylearn, 
          epochs=600, 
          batch_size=10000, 
          verbose=0, 
          validation_split=0
        )
```

Unfortunately, at this point, I have no idea how to figure out what's going wrong. The kernel just dies without any kind of explanation, even though for all I can see everything up to this point is going exactly how it went in the authors' upload of the notebook.

Comment: Can you add all of your imports to the code above?

Comment: Try changing `optimizer = "Nadam"` and see what happens

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus I get some output! I am not sure if this is the output I want, so I'm gonna run the notebook from this point on and get back to you if something looks off. Do you have any idea why ```optimizer="Nadam"``` works and ```optimizer=optimizer_nadam()``` doesn't?

Comment: Something about the definition. The way I have seen people compile models in R is doing `loss = "x", optimizer = "y"`, whereas you are using the function `optimizer_nadam()` in the optimizer parameter. Lets see how the execution goes.

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus I have edited my question. Thank you for your help! I will rerun the fit function with ```verbose=1``` to see where it crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249987/discussion-between-darknessplusplus-and-j-grunenwald).